# How to create negative datetime in python 2.7

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime, isodate

I need to insert into mongo db some BC dates but I cant create datetime with negative value like `datetime.datetime(-2000, 2, 1)`, but in mongodb it is possible to do with IsoDate, so how can i create negative dates in python?
I'm currently using python 2.7, and i do it on purpouse, for the project.

Comment: negative date time is a nonsense

Comment: I was just looking at [the source of the `datetime` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/datetime.py), and unfortunately it appears the minimum-date limitation is baked pretty deeply into the module. I’m not sure you’re realistically going to be able to use `datetime` with such dates. It’s already playing make-believe when it pretends that the Gregorian system goes back that far.

Comment: You can make it a string and append a negative sign. However, your manipulation via datetime functions is impossibre

Comment: @Kickaha: It’s perfectly sensical; why else would [BCE (Before Common Era)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era) exist?

Comment: So. There is no way to insert IsoDate with negative date?

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7's datetime library can only handle AD dates. If you need to go back further than that you will have to look at other libraries such as the `Time` class in [Astropy](http://www.astropy.org/) or `date` in [datautil](https://github.com/okfn/datautil/blob/master/swiss/date.py#L25).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to load and insert BC dates with those libraries?

Comment: I mean load and insert in mongodb. And it would be stil IsoDate in mongo?