# How to convert incomplete and BC Wikidata dates to timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

The [Wikidata date format](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Dates#Precision) looks like this:

`+2018-03-26T00:00:00Z`

So if Douglas Adams was born on `+1952-03-11T00:00:00Z`

Then I can use Python to get the timestamp like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
datestring = '+1952-03-11T00:00:00Z'
dt_obj = parse(datestring[1:])
print(dt_obj.timestamp())
```

`>>> -562032000.0`

As you can see here I cannot use the *+ -* value, which indicates that the date in AD or BC.

Moreover, I cannot work with an incomplete date:

For example Genghis Khan `+1162-00-00T00:00:00Z`(day and month missing)

And dates in BC that are also incomplete: Plato `-0427-00-00T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Related question: [BC dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857797/bc-dates-in-python).

Comment: Also can look at [How to create negative datetime in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161570/how-to-create-negative-datetime-in-python-2-7), where they suggest using [Astropy](http://www.astropy.org/) or [datautil](https://pypi.org/project/datautil) (not the same as [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/), confusingly enough) instead of the standard [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module cannot handle negative (BC) dates, but [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) can. It allows you to parse both positive and negative dates, although for some reason it only allows no sign symbol (assumes positive) or negative symbol; maybe it's worth raising an issue, as [the ISO 8601 standard is supposed to support it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years). The missing months and days, though, are not (afaik) part of the standard; you can split by `'-00'` as a kinda-hacky-but-effective solution. A complete function could look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def get_timestamp(date_str):
    # Probably not necessary
    date_str = date_str.strip()
    # Remove + sign
    if date_str[0] == '+':
        date_str = date_str[1:]
    # Remove missing month/day
    date_str = date_str.split('-00', maxsplit=1)[0]
    # Parse date
    dt = np.datetime64(date_str)
    # As Unix timestamp (choose preferred datetype)
    return dt.astype('<M8[s]').astype(np.int64)

date1 = '+1952-03-11T00:00:00Z'
date2 = '-0427-00-00T00:00:00Z'
print('Timestamp for {}: {}'.format(date1, get_timestamp(date1)))
# Timestamp for +1952-03-11T00:00:00Z: -562032000
print('Timestamp for {}: {}'.format(date2, get_timestamp(date2)))
# Timestamp for -0427-00-00T00:00:00Z: -75641990400
```

Comment: Opened [NumPy issue #10810](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10810) about signed positive dates.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: [NumPy issue #10810](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10810) is now fixed, I suppose the fix will be in for v1.14.3 / v1.15.